# Disaster trying to upgrade EE1 to EE2 - need help!

Tags: ee2, ee1, ee2-upgrades

I need some serious help guys!

I am running a large and popular website on ee 1.70. I want to upgrade to version 2 so this is what I did:

1. copied all files and folders, and made a backup sql file of the database
2. created a new database
3. created a new folder on the server called /test/
4. imported the sql file into the new database
5. copied all folders and files into /test/ folder and changed permissions where necessary.
6. Changed the config file to show the new database location

When I tried to log on to the control panel from here, I got a table error, and the advice found online was to start the ee2 upgrade. *I'm sure this is where things went wonky.*

I followed the upgrade instructions by renaming index.php and system and theme folders to _old. I uploaded the ee2 files. I restored some 1.x files. I ran the upgrade and it stopped part way through and gave me an ugly, non-css version of my site. I tried the upgrade again and had the same result.

Then when I went to my normal, live site, I got nothing but "Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; Invalid Preference Data"! **My site is gone!** The real one! How did that happen?

I restored my original files and folders onto the server and am still getting the site error message. How do I get my site back? And how to I continue to upgrade in the /test/ folder if it won't complete?

I'm panicking :(

Comment: do you have a backup?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't change the config file to use your new database information or paths. You'll need to get your backup into place on the live site.

Comment: I did change the config file, which is a worry. Are you saying I should actually re-upload the sql file?

Comment: A few questions (fully disclosing that I have not done a 1.xx to 2.xx upgrade): - How are you accessing the "test" site - via a subdomain?
- Can you double (and triple) check your paths to make sure they are set correctly? - Is the system folder "above root", and did you use the same location for both the live and test site? (the only reason why I can think of that it would have messed with your live site) It sounds like there is are settings that might be (or have been) mixed up between the live and test site.

Comment: Maybe my mistake was thinking I could copy the site and upgrade it from a subfolder on my server (which is running the other site in a different folder). I thought If I created a different database and changed the config file that would work. But it obviously didn't. That's another problem for another day. The problem I'm facing now is that my live site has been affected and I don't know how, and I don't know how to roll it backwards. Just copying the backed up files and folders doesn't seem to be working. Do I need to replace the sql file?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an update on the situation...

I copied the installation to a new location. When I tried to view the control panel, I received a table error. All the advice online said to power on with the upgrade, so I followed the upgrade instructions and ran the upgrade script.

**Where I went wrong is that I stupidly forgot to change the config file when restoring the 1.x files (I had changed the config file during the move, and forgot to do it again during the upgrade).** It botched my live database because the config file was pointing it to the old database, not the new one. I'm currently waiting for the database to be restored by the host because my backup file is returning errors.

Silly error with big consequences. Fingers crossed it has a happy ending.

Comment: Seriously, go get http://eeharbor.com/safeharbor or http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/backup-pro right now and install it - NEVER be at the mercy of a hosts backup solution.

Comment: Will do. I had a backup module installed, but the sql file that it produced turned out faulty. Never know til you need it, right?

Comment: yup - there's no worse feeling than a failed site with no reliable backup. Also, in future, I'd recommending doing your upgrade offline rather in the live environment.